# ScrollView react native doesn't show children with absolute position

Tags: react-native

Before asking this question , i checked all answers with the same topic but i didn't find an answer to fix my simple issue . I have a ScrollView that contains a text with a position absolute . This simple example doesn't work and doesn't show the text inside the scrollView .
Here is my example:

```
       import React, { Component } from "react";
       import { ScrollView, View, Text } from "react-native";

       class App extends Component {
         render() {
          return (
             <ScrollView style={{ height: 200, width: 100, backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", position: "absolute" }}>
                   Hello world
                </Text>
             </ScrollView>
             );
            }
           }

         export default App;
```

Please do you know how to fix it (I have to keep the absolute position of the child for multiple reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it doesn't really make sense for a component to have position: absolute in a ScrollView since it doesn't have a fixed height. The container does have a fixed height but its content not, that's the purpose of a ScrollView, its content is scrollable. For example, try this :

```
       import React, { Component } from "react";
       import { ScrollView, View, Text } from "react-native";

       class App extends Component {
         render() {
          return (
             <ScrollView
               style={{ height: 200, width: 100, backgroundColor: "blue" }}
               contentContainerStyle={{ height: 300, backgroundColor: 'brown' }}
            >
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", position: "absolute" }}>
                   Hello world
                </Text>
             </ScrollView>
             );
            }
           }

         export default App; contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'brown' }}
```

Notice the added style `contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'brown' }}`. This sets a height to its content. However its height won't be dynamic anymore, you can't scroll anymore if the actual content is greater in size which defeats the purpose of a ScrollView. Anyway, it's just a test. If you do this, you'll see that it works, the text is correctly displayed.

What you have to understand is you can't absolute position the contents relative to the ScrollView since it doesn't have any height unless you specify one like above. However, what you can do is wrapping the Text component in a View component and applying a height on this View like so :

```
<ScrollView style={{ height: 300, backgroundColor: 'orange' }} contentContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'brown' }}>
      {/* note this here */}
      <View style={{ height: 700 }}>
        <Text style={
          {fontWeight: "bold",
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 45,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            height: 500
          }}>
          Hello world
        </Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
```

One last thing, should the element always be relative to the ScrollView (the text remains even if you scroll)? Then just use a wrapper around the ScrollView, add the Text component inside and use position absolute on it.

Comment: thank u alot . You saved my time . Yes what was missing was contentContainerStyle . I should keep the absolute position of children because it's a shared code with my layout in react js so i should  keep the maximum shared style .

Answer (score 1):

I took your code example and I only put a `width` on the style of `ScrollView` and it worked.
However, I want to mention that if your items that are displayed inside the scrollview are having `position: "absolute"`, their dimensions (`height`, `width`) are ignored. So, I leave you here an example as you should display them in order to avoid their overlapping, because you have to "simulate" their height and therefore you have to add some value for `top`.

```js
 const items = ['Hello world 1', 'Hello world 2', 'Hello world 3']
 
 <ScrollView style={{ height: 200, width: 300, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <Text style={
            {fontWeight: "bold", 
            position: 'absolute',
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            top: index * 40
            }}>
              {item}
            </Text>
          ))}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but what as i want to display as children are buttons , view, input text ... setting the contentContainerStyle solves my problem